# What happens to questions to which the answers are outdated?

Tags: discussion, questions

What ought to happen to the questions that have outdated answers or to which the answers give outdated links? Is it okay to ask the question again?

Comment: Can you give an example of this happening on this site? Seems unlikely to me.

Comment: The network-wide policy is to add a new answer and let voting do the rest. Which of course doesn't work, but there you go. Leaving comments on the outdated answers sometimes makes the posters edit in updates.

Comment: @Raphael Second answer on: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6089/applications-of-propositional-dynamic-logic

Comment: What does that example illustrate? And what does it have to do with [cs.SE]? ;) Furthermore, the answers were written within an hour of each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't ask the question again.  If you find an old question that is unanswered but you're still interested in, you can provide a bounty.  This will bring it back to the front page and bring it some attention.

If the existing answers are outdated but you can provide a more up-to-date answer, you can write a new answer and hope for voting to eventually vote your answer above the others.

Generally speaking, I would expect that outdated answers might be rare on this site.  This site tends to be mostly about the science, and hopefully in most cases the science doesn't change too much.  There will be exceptions, certainly, but it might be less common than on technology-focused sites.